# JavaScript with c# doesn't work

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

`LoadClientScriptMessage` function doesn't work while `Response.Redirect("SamePage.aspx");` works well!

```
if (command2.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0)
{
     LoadClientScriptMessage("Something went wrong!");
}
else
{
     LoadClientScriptMessage("It is OK!");
     Response.Redirect("SamePage.aspx");
}
```

Here is the implementation of `LoadClientScriptMessage`:

```
private void LoadClientScriptMessage(string message)
{
    StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();

    script.Append(@"<script language='javascript'>");
    script.Append(@"alert('" + message + "');");
    script.Append(@"</script>");

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", script.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You want to show alert & redirect the user and complaining that it doesn't work ?

Comment: Or is it the first call when if condition evaluates to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you call `Response.Redirect("SamePage.aspx")` will actually
>   redirect the current request and you will not see any response
>   rendered for the current request.

All you get here is a new page. If you still want to see the alert and redirect then remove Response.Redirect and redirect using javascript `window.location.href`

```
 LoadClientScriptMessage("It is OK!");
 //Response.Redirect("SamePage.aspx");
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirct", 
  "window.location.href='somepage'",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you write `Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(Sample));` at pageload?
and add in web.config

```
<system.web>

<httpHandlers>
 <add verb="POST,GET" path="ajax/*.ashx" type="Ajax.PageHandlerFactory,Ajax"/>

 </httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Alert Message')</script>");
```